# How do I sent data to element's grandchildren in LitElement?

Tags: web-component, lit-element

How I could efficiently pass `value` from `MyElement` to `GrandChildrenElement`?

**index.html**

```
 <my-element></my-element>
```

**myElement.ts**

```
 @customElement('my-element')
 export class MyElement extends LitElement {
   value = 'foo';

   onChangeValue() {
   this.value = 'bar';
   }
   render() {
    return html`
     <child-element></child-element>
     `;
    
   }
 }
```

**childElement.ts**

```
 @customElement('child-element')
 export class ChildElement extends LitElement {
  ...

   render() {
    return html`
     <grandchild-element></grandchild-element>
     `;
   }
 }
```

**grandChildElement.ts**

```
 @customElement('grandchild-element')
 export class GrandChildElement extends LitElement {
   @property()
   value = '';

   render() {
     return html`
     <p>${value}</p>
     `;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your Grandfather can tell you something (function call) or you can listen (Event)

Comment: thanks for your reply @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, according lit docs, communication through events should be for from children to parents cases. I did not understand the other alternative

Comment: I never read the Lit docs. Events can go either way if you implement an EventBus: https://css-tricks.com/lets-create-a-lightweight-native-event-bus-in-javascript/

Comment: Hi! The [Lit youtube channel has a video on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9mxtnoy9Qw). The video covers the pattern of passing props down to children, and using events to communicate from children back to parents. For very deep passing of properties (prop drilling) there are solutions such as using "labs/context" and using a state management tool such as MobX, Redux etc.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way would be to pass the value down through the child element using properties:

```
@customElement('my-element')
export class Element extends LitElement {
  @state()
  value = 'foo';
  
  toggle() {
    if (this.value === 'foo') {
      this.value = 'bar';
    } else {
      this.value = 'foo';
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return html`
        <my-child value="${this.value}"></my-child>
        <button @click="${this.toggle}">Toggle</button>
    `;
  }
}

@customElement('my-child')
export class Child extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: 'string' })
  value;
  
  render() {
    return html`<my-grandchild value="${this.value}"></my-grandchild>`;
  }
}

@customElement('my-grandchild')
export class GrandChild extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: 'string' })
  value;
  
  render() {
    return html`<div>${this.value}</div>`;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-VG9nZ2xlPC9idXR0b24-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-JHt0aGlzLnZhbHVlfTwvZGl2PmA7XG4gIH1cbn0ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJpbmRleC5odG1sIiwiY29udGVudCI6IjwhRE9DVFlQRSBodG1sPlxuPGhlYWQ-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vbWFpbi5qc1wiPjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuPC9oZWFkPlxuPGJvZHk-XG4gIDxteS1lbGVtZW50PjwvbXktZWxlbWVudD5cbjwvYm9keT5cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6InBhY2thZ2UuanNvbiIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJ7XG4gIFwiZGVwZW5kZW5jaWVzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImxpdFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwiQGxpdC9yZWFjdGl2ZS1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjEuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4zLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWh0bWxcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIlxuICB9XG59IiwiaGlkZGVuIjp0cnVlfV0)

---

But if you're looking for a way to bypass the elements in between, you'll have to get a bit more creative.

One solution could be to have the element collect subscribers and update them when its value changes.

In the example below, the grandchild dispatches a "subscribe" event when it connects, which bubbles up to the element. The element then gets the grandchild (via the event's composedPath), updates its value, and adds it to the set of subscribers. When the element changes its value within `toggle()`, it updates its subscribers.

```
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property, state} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('my-element')
export class Element extends LitElement {
  value = 'foo';
  subscribers = new Set();
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('subscribe', (e: CustomEvent) => {
      const composedTarget = e.composedPath()[0] as any;
      composedTarget.value = this.value;
      this.subscribers.add(composedTarget);
    });
    this.addEventListener('unsubscribe', (e: CustomEvent) => {
      const composedTarget = e.composedPath()[0];
      this.subscribers.delete(composedTarget);
    });
  }
  
  toggle() {
    if (this.value === 'foo') {
      this.value = 'bar';
    } else {
      this.value = 'foo';
    }
    for (const subscriber of this.subscribers) {
      grandchild.value = this.value;
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return html`
        <my-child></my-child>
        <button @click="${this.toggle}">Toggle</button>
    `;
  }
}

@customElement('my-child')
export class Child extends LitElement { 
  render() {
    return html`<my-grandchild></my-grandchild>`;
  }
}

@customElement('my-grandchild')
export class GrandChild extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: 'string' })
  value;
  
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('subscribe', { bubbles: true, composed: true }));
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    super.disconnectedCallback();
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('unsubscribe', { bubbles: true, composed: true }));
  }
  
  render() {
    return html`<div>${this.value}</div>`;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=W3sibmFtZSI6Im1haW4udHMiLCJjb250ZW50IjoiaW1wb3J0IHtodG1sLCBjc3MsIExpdEVsZW1lbnR9IGZyb20gJ2xpdCc7XG5pbXBvcnQge2N1c3RvbUVsZW1lbnQsIHByb3BlcnR5LCBzdGF0ZX0gZnJvbSAnbGl0L2RlY29yYXRvcnMuanMnO1xuXG5AY3VzdG9tRWxlbWVudCgnbXktZWxlbWVudCcpXG5leHBvcnQgY2xhc3MgRWxlbWVudCBleHRlbmRzIExpdEVsZW1lbnQge1xuICB2YWx1ZSA9ICdmb28nO1xuICBzdWJzY3JpYmVycyA9IG5ldyBTZXQoKTtcbiAgXG4gIGNvbnN0cnVjdG9yKCkge1xuICAgIHN1cGVyKCk7XG4gICAgdGhpcy5hZGRFdmVudExpc3RlbmVyKCdzdWJzY3JpYmUnLCAoZTogQ3VzdG9tRXZlbnQpID0-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-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-XG48L2JvZHk-XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJwYWNrYWdlLmpzb24iLCJjb250ZW50Ijoie1xuICBcImRlcGVuZGVuY2llc1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJsaXRcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcIkBsaXQvcmVhY3RpdmUtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4xLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMy4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1odG1sXCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsImhpZGRlbiI6dHJ1ZX1d)